# Showing: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status - on building C program

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling

I'm fairly new to programming. These are the files I downloaded for a C project that I have to do. They work fine for everyone but I am unable to move forward because of the error that VSCode is throwing.

Link to repo: [Project1 Movie Table](https://github.com/drunkcaterpillar/Project-1-Movie-Table)

The error:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\sanyu\Desktop\CS354\Project1\student_functions.c -o C:\Users\sanyu\Desktop\CS354\Project1\student_functions.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I looked at similar problems faced by others but I could not figure out how to solve my issue.

Comment: You are trying to link `student_functions.c` as an executable but that source file does not have a `main` function. You need to compile the source files into objects first and then link them all together. If you do not understand what that means then you really should start with a simpler example first.

Comment: `undefined reference to `WinMain@16'` , suggests you're compiling this as a Windows GUI or native program, not a *console* program. Even if you have a `main` nobody cares about it windows apps unless you tell it that is what should be used as your entry point via a subsystem switch. Check your toolchain switches for how to specify console vs. gui configurations (I'd tell you which to use, but I steer clear of MinGW when it comes to Windows, opting for MS's toolchain instead).